# Error : 'Can't write; duplicate key in table..' when creating the db table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a mapping table which mapped with three tables. When I run the table creation SQL it' shows a error like

> SQL Error (1022): Can't write; duplicate key in table 'mytable'

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id_one` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `id_two` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `id_three` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `attribute_one` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY  (`id_one`, `id_two`, `id_three`, `attribute_one`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_one` FOREIGN KEY (`id_one`) REFERENCES `table_one` (`id_one`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_two` FOREIGN KEY (`id_two`) REFERENCES `table_two` (`id_two`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_three` FOREIGN KEY (`id_three`) REFERENCES `table_three` (`id_three`)
);
```

My Question is why it's giving an error like duplicating at table creation. How can I overcome this.

Comment: `CONSTRAINT \`id_three\`` try `CONSTRAINT \`fk_three\``

Comment: sorry that my naming conventions make it confused. You can think `tableone` as a different name I changed it to `mytable`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried but the result is same still getting the error.

Comment: I seem to recall that mysql requires the key name to be unique across the whole db. You may have a duplicate key name somewhere.have a look at information_schema.innodb_sys_foreign. or just drop the foreign key names one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: @P. Salmon Yes I found that `fk_one` was use in another table. After changing the name it works.